# cpuinfo of my galaxy note

Tags: android, linux, cpu

that's quite strange but the cpuinfo of my galaxy note return me.

```
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS    : 1592.52
processor   : 1
BogoMIPS    : 2786.91
```

I suspect that both the core should have the same bogomips values no ?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Comment: Ok. Let says that I'd like to know the device performance for activate some functionality of my project. Is there another way to have a kind of value representing the power of the device ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering Android, I don't think there is an easy way but may be how they do it internally in [ActivityManager.isHighEndGfx()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java#L212) can provide a hint to you.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU throttles up by the time bogomips is run against the 2nd core.